# kendo alert on click ok set custom actions

Tags: events, kendo-ui

I am using KendoUI for alert. code is given below :

```
kendo.alert("Hello ").then(function () {
      window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
});
```

But 'then' is not function showing that error. So I want do some action on Ok click. How to do that? Or any other way we can do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

ezanker's response is not right and links to improper documentation.

The kendo.alert method ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/alert)) does not return anything whereas kendo.confirm ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/confirm)) and kendo.prompt ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/prompt)) return a jQuery promise.

Therefore any jQuery deferred callback on `kendo.alert` would not do anything. You can confirm this by looking at the underlying code ([here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/96936af7b6962d219b9672601ee3b36a50a15bea/src/kendo.dialog.js#L1021)) where there is no action property being set for the "Ok" button's property definition.

An alternative to using a promise callback would be to bind to the hide event as per this official suggestion ([here](https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-jquery-ui/1462037-predefined-kendo-alert-should-support-chaining)):

```js
$(function() {
  kendo.alert('Hello').bind('hide', function(){
    console.log('the OK button was clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/6.3.0/default/default-ocean-blue.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.425/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.425/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.425/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

kendo.alert does not support a then().

Kendo.prompt and kendo.confirm support .then() , .done(), .fail()

See [DEMO](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/predefined-dialogs) and [DOCS](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/confirm)